# Is anyone else having problems with using htop on High Sierra?

Tags: terminal, iterm, high-sierra

Since the upgrade to High Sierra my MacBook is crashing regularly in a catastrophic way that forces me to trigger a hard reset every time.

I suspect [htop](http://hisham.hm/htop/) being the culprit, but I can't tell for sure.

This is what happened about half a dozen times now:

I'm working in either iTerm2 or the Terminal app. Suddenly and seemingly at random iTerm2/Terminal crashes. I'm still able to Force Quit it then.

But then the whole system is left in a really messed up state where I can't start any Apps anymore. Even worse, triggering a restart won't succeed in shutting down the system. My only option left then is to hard-reset the MacBook.

First I suspected iTerm2 and used the Terminal app instead. But exactly the same thing then also happened using the latter. It does not seem to be connected to anything particular I'm doing in the Terminal.

I do have the habit though to always have an instance of htop (version 2.0.2, installed via `brew install htop`) running in some terminal pane to be able to conveniently monitor processes and CPU/Memory usage while I'm working.

So a running htop instance is the only common precondition for the crashes I can identify.

Because I don't know how to further encircle this problem, I resort to asking here:

Is anyone else experiencing (similar) problems with running htop on High Sierra? And does anyone maybe even have a solution for this?

Suggestions about what I could do to get to the bottom of this would also be very welcome.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, both on a hackintosh and a real macbook pro.

Comment: Thanks for replying, good to know I'm not the only one! Are you sure that htop is the root cause for the problem? Did it ever happen to you when *not* running htop? Do you know of any way to positively confirm the assumption that htop is to be blamed?

Comment: I am not sure htop is the root cause, however this issue only ever happened when I was running htop or immediately after closing it. The fact that the system remains unstable even after force quitting iTerm/Terminal.app hints at some resource starvation. I suspect some change in High Sierra is making htop leak mach ports.

Comment: All right, someone filed a [bug on GitHub](https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/issues/682) for this already two days ago...

Comment: same problem here

Comment: Oh my god. I am debugging this issue for the whole night. I suspected broken APFS (because of unrepairable snapshot errors in disk utility) vmware + docker/hyperkit and so on. For me, the crash takes down the whole system, finder sees only few files (if it launches at all), whole system acts as the disk is read only or something. Must have something to do with XPC or gatekeeper or something. In all cases I was running htop in terminal and suspected it too, but I didn't want to believe that it does this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I the meantime lots of people have reported the same behavior on [GitHub](https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/issues/682).

Also, I'm 96.73% sure that `htop` does *not* crash when started with `sudo`. I guess that's the best workaround until someone gets around to fix the root cause.

Answer (score 2):

I found another (safer than sudo) workaround: launching it with valgrind does the trick for me:

`valgrind htop`

you can install using Homebrew by running:

`brew install valgrind`