# all process related tools stop working sometimes

Tags: terminal, high-sierra, performance, bug

So, for the 4th time now, all process tools on my mac stopped working (`top`, `pgrep`, `kill`, Activity Monitor, etc).

I can't find a pattern nor any log on what's causing it.

When it happens, iTerm freezes and I can't open other terminal apps. I can start a terminal through VisualStudio Code though.

I tried to use `ps`, `top` et al to find what is wrong, but the commands never output anything (seems like they "freeze" or something).

Activity Monitor don't show any processes at all.

The only way to "fix" the issue is to reboot, which I dislike (if I where to reboot to fix things I would use windows xp).

So, I don't know what to do or where to look. Has anyone ever seen anything like this? What can I do?

---

**EDIT**:

macOS 10.13.2

**EDIT2**:

I didn't have htop opened when the issue happened, so I don't think it is related to the htop question

**EDIT3**:

Just rebooted my mac and I indeed had a tab open with `htop` running. So it is probably the same thing.

Comment: Do you use `htop` by any chance?

Comment: Please include: which version of MacOS you are using, if you checked your filesystem with DU.

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan yes, but it also stop working when this bug happens...

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the way htop and High Sierra interact. https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/issues/682

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/300185/4007

Comment: I wasn't running htop at the time but OMG this is a weird bug

Comment: I had htop running, restarted my mac and opened iterm and it restored the output... sorry about the confusion.

Comment: don't know how to mark my question as dupe now...

Comment: Just delete it.